# Loop over object distionary with no keys from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, amazon-web-services

**Create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE comprehensive_risk_summary (
    set_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    calculation_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    label VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    critical_count VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    median_risk VARCHAR(60)
);
```

SQL table that inserts the data as:

```
INSERT INTO comp_risk VALUES (
    UNHEX(REPLACE("5a9dbfca-74d6-471a-af27-31beb4b53bb2", "-","")),
    "NOW()"
    "{5/27/20, Apr. 2020, Aug 2019, Dec 2019}",
    "{2, 4, 5, 4}",
    "{1.05, 1.25, 1.07, 1.13}"
);
```

On querying this table, `select * from comp_risk`, the response is as:

```
"data": {
            "patient_set_id": "5a9dbfca-74d6-471a-af27-31beb4b53bb2",
            "calculation_time": "2020-12-01 11:57:34",
            "label": "{5/27/20, Apr. 2020, Aug 2019, Dec 2019}",
            "critical_count": "{2, 4, 5, 4}",
            "median_risk": "{1.05, 1.25, 1.07, 1.13}"
        }
```

I need the ultimate data in the format something like this:

```
{
    "set_id": "5a9dbfca-74d6-471a-af27-31beb4b53bb2",
    "calculation_time": "2020-12-01 11:57:34",
    "internals" : [
             {  "label" : "5/27/20",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                  "count": 2
                },
                "median": 1.05
             },
             {  "label" : "Apr. 2019",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                  "count": 4
                },
                "median": 1.25
             },
             {  "label" : "Aug. 2019",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                  "count": 5
                },
                "median": 1.07
             },
             {  "label" : "Dec. 2019",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                  "count": 4
                },
                "median": 1.13
             }];
  }
```

I am unable to figure out how to implement the same, as the data returned from the database is returning a JSON without keys, just values. I looped over the object row, say, `"median_risk": "{1.05, 1.25, 1.07, 1.13}"` like so:

```
for(ele in median_risk){
    console.log('--->', ele);
}
```

but it returns illogical output like:

```
---> 1
---> 2
---> 3
---> 4
---> 5
---> 6
---> 7
---> 8
---> 9
---> 10
---> 11
---> 12
---> 13
```

I am quite stuck for a while, if anyone can help me to resolve this or any other better approach, highly appreciated!

**MySQL version**: 5.7
**Using AWS RDS Aurora DB with Nodejs**

Comment: Did you try `median_risk.split(', ')`?

Comment: @Anatoly. Yea it returns new array containing the whole object like this: `[ '{1.11', ' 2.8', ' 2.5', ' 0.3}' ]`

Comment: @Akina I've updated the question

Comment: @Akina My bad. I fixed the insert command

Comment: `NOW()` must be NOT enclosed with quotes - with them this is string literal, not function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can to advice node.js solution for this problem:

```js
const data = {
    "patient_set_id": "5a9dbfca-74d6-471a-af27-31beb4b53bb2",
    "calculation_time": "2020-12-01 11:57:34",
    "label": "{5/27/20, Apr. 2020, Aug 2019, Dec 2019}",
    "critical_count": "{2, 4, 5, 4}",
    "median_risk": "{1.05, 1.25, 1.07, 1.13}"
};

const labels = data.label.split(',');
const critical_counts = data.critical_count.split(',');
const median_risks = data.median_risk.split(',');

const internals = labels.reduce((internals, l, i)=>{
    const clean = (s) => s.replace('{','').replace('}','').trim();
    internals.push({
        label: clean(l),
        cat4_cnt: {count: clean(critical_counts[1])},
        median: clean(median_risks[i])
    });
    return internals;
},[])

console.log(internals);
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. Can you suggest a small thing if the MYSQL data approach I'm following is correct to insert nested data into the table?

Comment: I don't know about your case, but actually MySQL is not best choice to store nested data. I advice to look MongoDB as document storage. Any way if you want so store JSON data in MySQL store it in JSON format. Look example: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=bb89909b4a737aae3057fadad032b067&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Just one last small query. I need to split this `const distribution_bins = "{[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, +INF], [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, +INF]}";`  into 2 separate arrays, which means, extract these 2 arrays out of this object. I'm trying like this: `distribution_bins.split('], ')`. But it is not throwing me correct data. Can you please confirm me if I am approaching it correctly?

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask, open separate question for it

Comment: Can you review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094551/extracting-arrays-out-of-a-single-object