# Extracting arrays out of a string that isn't valid JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a data object that is fetched from some pre-defined database table's column that contains two arrays in a string like this:

```
const distribution_bins = "{[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, +INF], [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, 0.36, 0.48, 0.6, 0.72, 0.84, 0.96, +INF]}";
```

I need to extract separate arrays out of it as:

```
 array1 = [0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, +INF],
 array2 = [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, 0.36, 0.48, 0.6, 0.72, 0.84, 0.96, +INF]
```

For this, I am performing the operation over `distribution_bins` like this:

```
console.log(distribution_bins.split('],'));
```

But doing so, result in data like this:

```
[
  '{[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, +INF',
  ' [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, 0.36, 0.48, 0.6, 0.72, 0.84, 0.96, +INF]}'
]
```

Notice the missing `]` close bracket after the first array `[0.0, 0.3,....,2.7, +INF'`.

Not sure if the split() done is not correct. Any help to rectify this is appreciated :)

Comment: Your first snippet is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: is it an object? or a string?

Comment: mate what is +INF? it doesn't mean anything in javascript.

Comment: Your "object" inside of the string doesn't have keys for the array values. Did you mean to make it an array of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not valid JSON, but it's close. If you have any control over it, you should change it to be valid Json. If you don't you could do something like this:

```
// Create keys for the properties of the objects. This uses the offset
// of the start of the property as its key.
let jsonify = distribution_bins.replace(/{/g, "[");
jsonify = jsonify.replace(/}/g, "]");

// Wrap +INF in quotes.
jsonify = jsonify.replace(/\+INF/g, `"+INF"`);

// Parse.
const distribution_data = JSON.parse(jsonify);
```

Comment: Yes, I don't have power over the data received. And, trying the solution you provided, it is throwing error : `TypeError: JSON.decode is not a function`

Comment: Supposed to be JSON.parse.

Comment: Can you help explain the output ? `{
  '1': [
         0,    0.3,
       0.6,    0.9,
       1.2,    1.5,
       1.8,    2.1,
       2.4,    2.7,
    '+INF'
  ],
  '59': [
       0,   0.12,
    0.24,   0.36,
    0.48,    0.6,
    0.72,   0.84,
    0.96, '+INF'
  ]`   What these '1' & '59' random number represent?

Comment: That is an object with keys generated by the position of the opening brackets in the original string. To get an array of the values use `Object.values(distribution_data)` (this should be added to the answer)

Comment: Yes, or instead of the first thing, replace "{" with "[" and "}" with "]".

Comment: That's a far less convoluted solution than adding keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this piece with string and array manipulations, I took the extra steps to make the code example clear, but you can optimize and reduce the line of codes by using a map to go over the double array values.

```
let distribution_bins = "{[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, +INF], [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, 0.36, 0.48, 0.6, 0.72, 0.84, 0.96, +INF]}";

// clean up the edge "[{ }]" characters 
distribution_bins = distribution_bins.substring(2, distribution_bins.length-2);

// Create double dimension array, each one with a one string value
let doubleArray = distribution_bins.split("], [");
const doubleArraySplit0 = doubleArray[0].split(",");
const doubleArraySplit1 = doubleArray[1].split(",");

// Parse each string to a number using a map
const strToNum0 = doubleArraySplit0.map(str => parseFloat(str));
const strToNum1 = doubleArraySplit1.map(str => parseFloat(str));
console.log(strToNum0);
console.log(strToNum1);
```

As you can see on the screenshot below, it will print the end result of two arrays each one with actual numeric values rather than strings. The NaN should go away once you use real numbers instead of 'INF', which could be translated from string to numeric value.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your pattern is predetermined and you don't need a flexible solution to work in multiple scenarios, your solution is ok. You are close.

First you have to remove `{[` and `]}` then you split it into two parts with `split("], [")` and then finally you make your 2 part of string into array by using `split(", ")`

```js
var distribution_bins = "{[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, +INF], [0.0, 0.12, 0.24, 0.36, 0.48, 0.6, 0.72, 0.84, 0.96, +INF]}";

// Remove {[ and ]}
distribution_bins = distribution_bins.replace("{[", "");
distribution_bins = distribution_bins.replace("]}", "");

// split string to 2 seperate parts of your arrays
var [array1, array2] = distribution_bins.split('], [');

// Make first part of string to array 1
array1 = array1.split(", ");

// Make second part of string to array 2
array2 = array2.split(", ");

console.log(array1, array2);
```